# How to mask line border with parent corner radius in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm using next js for my web application, and I have come to this requirement I need.  Please refer the below image:

[image]

The line is a progress bar which is a child of the parent div in the background. I want to be able to hide the start of the line behind its corresponding parent div.

Here is an example code for reference:

```css
.parent-div{
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
width: 320px;
height: 48px;
border-radius: 17px;
max-height: 48px;
}

.progress-bar{
height: 5px;
margin-top: 3px;
width: inherit;
border-radius: 17px;
background-color: #6d45fc;

}
```

```html
<html>
    <div class="parent-div">
        <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
</html>
```

How do i mask the line into the parent div

This is the expected output:

[image]

Comment: Could you also add the image of an expected result?

Comment: `overflow:hidden` on the parent if the gray part is the parent, maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `overflow: hidden` property to parent

```css
.parent-div{
position: relative;
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
width: 320px;
height: 48px;
border-radius: 17px;
max-height: 48px;
background-color: gray;
overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-bar{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
height: 5px;
margin-top: 3px;
width: inherit;
border-radius: 17px;
background-color: #6d45fc;

}
```

```html
<html>
    <div class="parent-div">
        <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't know it was that simple, thank you ! <3